# How to prove that a function is total on its domain?

Tags: isabelle

I have the following theory:

```
theory Color 
imports Main 

begin 

datatype color = RED | GREEN 

function invert :: "color => color" 
where 
  "invert RED   = GREEN" 
| "invert GREEN = RED  " 
apply (pat_completeness) 
apply auto 
done 
termination by lexicographic_order 

lemma invert_univ: "invert_dom = (λx. True)"
```

I would like to prove that `invert` is total on its whole domain, so `invert_dom` defines the universal set on datatype `color`. How can proceed with this proof? Or, should I formulate this by other means?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you really do not need to use `function` here. The termination proof for this function is trivial and can be found automatically, so you can just write

```
fun invert :: "color ⇒ color" 
where 
  "invert RED   = GREEN" 
| "invert GREEN = RED"
```

or, since it is primitively recursive on the datatype `color`:

```
primrec invert :: "color ⇒ color" 
where 
  "invert RED   = GREEN" 
| "invert GREEN = RED"
```

or even just

```
definition invert :: "color ⇒ color" where
  "invert c = (case c of RED ⇒ GREEN | GREEN ⇒ RED)"
```

In the last case, you have to unfold the definition of `invert` manually using the lemma `invert_def`.

Now to your actual question: technically, in HOL, *every* function is total. This is necessarily the case because logics in which expressions can have no value at all tend to get very messy. You can “simulate” nontotality by returning `undefined` on some inputs, which is some arbitrary value that you know nothing about. `undefined :: int` is some integer value – it could be 0, or it could be 42 or any other integer. For functions defined with the function package, this is only relevant if you let cases unspecified (e.g. by not giving an equation for one case) or if the function does not terminate on some inputs (then things get messy; if you want to do any reasoning about the function then, you have to prove it terminates on the input you give it first)

If you *have* given a termination proof – which you have, in this case, since the function trivially terminates – the `invert_dom` predicate is basically useless. You don't need it.

Otherwise, you can prove that `invert_dom` holds on a given input using the `invert.domintros` rules. Since they are rarely needed in practice, you have to switch their generation on manually, by using `function (domintros)` instead of `function`. Then you can prove the lemma you suggested like this:

```
lemma "invert_dom = (λ_. True)"
proof
  fix x show "invert_dom x = True"
    by (cases x) (auto intro: invert.domintros)
qed
```

But, again, the `*_dom` predicates are very rarely used in practice.

Comment: Thanks. I thought I needed _dom because I had found  AddShell.bit.psimps(1): bit_dom (BITV ?b ?bv) ⟹ bit (BITV ?b ?bv) = ?b and I wanted to prove the RHS of this implication, where this RHS is actually one clause of the definition of the bit function. I'll post this as a separate question.

Comment: If you have a terminating function, there are `_.simps` rules. Use those instead of `_.psimps`.

Comment: With primrec and definition I had bit_def - I did not have it with function -- and then apply (simp add: bit_def) did the trick.

Comment: `function` also generates a `_def` lemma, but it is something ugly and unusable. You should definitely have `.simps` lemmas if you proved termination, and those are the ones you want to use to unfold the definition.